# How to mock getters with Jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, mocking

I want to unit test this **TS** code with **Jest**:

MyClass.ts

```
import Dependency from "./Dependency";

export default class MyClass {
    public constructor(private dependency: Dependency) {}

    public DoIt(): string {
        return this.dependency.MyProp;
    }
}
```

It uses this class:

```
export default class Dependency {
    public get MyProp(): string {
        return "A string";
    }
}
```

This is my test so far:

```
import MyClass from "./MyClass";
import Dependency from "./Dependency";

jest.mock("./Dependency"); // Here we do auto mocking

it("connects with the server for match info messages", () => {
    // Arrange
    const dependency = new Dependency();
    const sut = new MyClass(dependency);
    // dependency.MyProp = "Another string"; // Cannot assign to 'MyProp' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)
    jest.spyOn(dependency, "MyProp", "get").mockReturnValueOnce("Another string"); // Error: MyProp property does not exist

    // Act
    const retval = sut.DoIt();

    // Assert
    expect(retval).toStrictEqual("Another string");
});
```

As noted in the comments, I can't properly mock the `MyProp` property. At runtime, it's `undefined` because auto mocking doesn't see it as a function so it ignored it.

**Question**: How to properly mock public properties on mocks without giving up auto mocking?

Answer (score 1):

Don't mock the `./Dependency` module with an auto-mocked version. Just remove `jest.mock()` statement, and it will work. We only need to use `jest.spyOn()` mock the `MyProp` getter method.

```
import MyClass from "./MyClass";
import Dependency from "./Dependency";

it("connects with the server for match info messages", () => {
    // Arrange
    const dependency = new Dependency();
    const sut = new MyClass(dependency);
    jest.spyOn(dependency, "MyProp", "get").mockReturnValueOnce("Another string"); // Error: MyProp property does not exist

    // Act
    const retval = sut.DoIt();

    // Assert
    expect(retval).toStrictEqual("Another string");
});
```

Comment: But then I'm using the actual Dependency class implementation. That's not what we want here. We are executing the actual constructor. It might have side effects and might also require its own dependencies.

Comment: @Jupiter Show the code to explain your question